# Why is my android application not running when it is not connected to the IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse

My android application makes a lot of API calls and all seem to be working when the device is connected to the computer and the IDE is open. The minute I close the IDE or unplug the device, I see that the application DOES NOT crash but it isn't receiving data anymore. Any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if you're connected to the internet when your phone is unplugged versus plugged in?

Comment: I figured out what the issue is.  I had a bunch of `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` statements for debugging in the AsyncTasks and all of them had to be commented out. Normalcy restored :)

Comment: You can also do:                     `if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is. I had a bunch of `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` statements for debugging in the AsyncTasks. Replace them with:

```
if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()){ 
   android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
}
```